# How does an organism know when to stop growing, whether it is already on the outermost layer?

Tags: development

When a multicellular organism is under its development how does the current outermost layer of cells "know" that they should not divide furthermore, as their bodyplan coded into DNA is already achieved. Is it because of morphogens or something else's work is in the background?

If it is entirely controlled by morpogens, than it would mean, that injecting a given morphogen to the outermost cells, would result in further increase in the organism's size?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Could you please expand your question because in this form it is unclear what you're asking and I do not really understand your question either.

Comment: @FloriOn - I think it's ok for me, I think I get what you're asking

Comment: @FloriOn - It is your sole decision :)

Comment: It is not the outermost layer of cells that determine tissue expansion. For example, during development the skull shapes itself to the expanding brain. I vote for question closure as it is badly researched. It definitely holds potential, and I encourage FloriOn to edit, but it does needs work.

Comment: @AliceD You are right, I have missed some important steps. But before the brain starts its development, the skull should be already in some place, for which it should have known the outer limit to its growing. I hope I am being clear here, as I am not sure about it.